# Qt Meta System Call constructor with parameters

Tags: qt, qtcore

I know that I can use `QMetaType` to create an object without parameters.

Another possible option is to use `QMetaObject` and call `newInstance`. But I need to get `QMetaObject` from something.

I tried to use `QMetaType::metaObjectForType`, but it always returns null pointer (but `QMetaType` is able to create the object).

```
QMetaObject const* metaObject = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(id); // return null pointer
   QObject*           object     =   (QObject*)QMetaType::create(id); // create the object
QMetaObject const* metaObject = object->metaObject(); // return not-null pointer
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the question is why `metaObjectForType` does not work for me.
The class is registered with `qRegisterMetaType`, also `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and `Q_OBJECT` are applied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, to pass parameters to methods, you needs some kind of reflection framework beyond plain C++. With Qt, the obivous choice is Qt Meta Object system with it's [`QMetaObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetaobject.html), though then you must derive your classes for `QObject`. After that, you need to do two things:

### 1. make constructor invokable

Signals and slots are invokable by default, but any other method you want to invoke through the meta object system needs to be explicitly marked as such. Example *myqobject.h*:

```
#ifndef MYQOBJECT_H
#define MYQOBJECT_H
#include <QObject>

class MyQObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE MyQObject(QObject *parent = 0); // tested with empty constructor in .cpp

};

#endif // MYQOBJECT_H
```

### 2. create your own mapping from class name string to the `QMetaObject`

[`QMetaType`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetatype.html) doc says: *"any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor, and a public destructor can be registered."* This rules out QObject, because they can't have copy constructors. You need to create your own mapping from name to the meta object. An example shown in this *main.cpp*:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore>

#include "myqobject.h"

// a global map for mapping strings to QMetaObjects,
// you need header file like this if you want to access it from other .cpp files:
//
// #include <QHash>
// #include <QString>
// class QMetaObject; // forward declaration, enough when only pointer is needed
// extern QHash<QString, const QMetaObject*> metaObjs;
//
QHash<QString, const QMetaObject*> metaObjs;

// optional: create a macro to avoid typing class name twice,
// #c surrounds macro argument with double quotes converting it to string
#define METAOBJS_INSERT(c) (metaObjs.insert(#c, &c::staticMetaObject))

int main()
{
    METAOBJS_INSERT(MyQObject);

    const QMetaObject *meta = metaObjs["MyQObject"];
    qDebug() << "Class name from staticMetaObject: " << meta->className();

    QObject *o = meta->newInstance(); // add constructor arguments as needed
    MyQObject *mo = qobject_cast<MyQObject*>(o);
    if (mo) qDebug() << "Class name from object instance: " << mo->metaObject()->className();
    else qDebug() << "Instance creation failed or created wrong class!";

    return 0;
}
```

If you do not want to use `QObject`, then you need to come up with some similar (probably lighter-weight and without separate compiler step) mechanism of your own.

Comment: It is not exactly what I want. When I try to create an object I don't really have the type of it. For example, I want to get `QWidget*`, and use name "MyWidget" to create it, and I don't know that it is class `MyWidget`.

Comment: I told that "I tried to use `QMetaType::metaObjectForType`, but it always returns null pointer (but `QMetaType` is able to create the object)." Any reason why it could happen?

Comment: Yes it works with "QObject*". See the updates please.

Comment: This started to bug me, so I did some research, and rewrote the answer from scratch (and deleted my earlier comments). I think that's the best you are going to get with C++. I don't know, but *boost* has all kinds of cool stuff, it may have some reflection features which you could use instead of Qt's, if you don't want to use QObject and don't want to roll your own mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The solution is in two steps:

1. call qRegisterMetaType() with a **pointer type**:
   qRegisterMetaType<**MyClass***>(). this will give you a valid
   QMetaObject with call of QMetaType::metaObjectForType(id);
2. make your constructor Q_INVOKABLE. this will enable a valid call to
   QMetaObject::newInstance

And also be sure that your class is derived from QObject and have a Q_OBJECT macro in it.

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    A(const A&) {}; // dummy copy contructor that do nothing to disable error message
    Q_INVOKABLE A(int test_value = 99999) : TestValue(test_value) {};
    int TestValue;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(A);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    qRegisterMetaType<A>(); //you do not need this
    qRegisterMetaType<A*>();//the real registration
    int type_id_for_A = QMetaType::type("A"); // valid type id (in my case = 403)
    const QMetaObject *meta_object_for_A = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(type_id_for_A); // returns NULL
    int type_id_for_A_ptr = QMetaType::type("A*"); // valid type id (in my case = 404)
    const QMetaObject *meta_object_for_A_tr = QMetaType::metaObjectForType(type_id_for_A_ptr); // returns NOT NULL
    A* A_obj= dynamic_cast<A*>(meta_object_for_A_tr->newInstance(Q_ARG(int, 12345)));
    int test_value = A_obj->TestValue; // returns 12345, not 99999
}
```